# C++ Adding Data to Unordered Map

Tags: c++

I am getting `double` type data from a table and passing it to an unordered map.

```
std::map<string, double> map_items;

for (unsigned int x = 0; x < array.size(); x++)
{
   string item = list[i];
   double data = array[x]; // error: a value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "double"
   map_items[item] = data
```

I realize that data[x] isn't a double but the underlying data is. How should I format this to send data to the map?

Comment: *I realize that data[x] isn't a double but the underlying data is* Please elaborate.

Comment: plz, provide a minimal produceble code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well array[x] itself isn't a double but it represents a double

Comment: What is `list`, what is `i`? Please provide a working example.

Comment: `map_items.insert (item, data);`? (and note, you have a `map`, not `unordered_map`) See [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) Also note: [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) means something I can copy from your question, save, compile and test without having to write code to make it compile.

Comment: @Dmitry list is just an array that I am iterating through further up.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Thanks for your reply. array[x] = 12.7584. Which is just some double value. There isn't much to run here, just wanted to know the correct way to append to the map. I'm new to C++, do I need an unordered map instead?

Comment: @apgujeong how could we guess that `list`, `array` and `data` (in your initial version) are the same structures? We are waiting for a working example where we wouldn't need to guess.

Comment: @apgujeong - you are on the right track. Add the header `<unordered_map>` and then declare `map_items` as `std::unordered_map<string, double> map_items;` The you will at least have an `unordered_map`. One you get a string in `item` and a double in `data`, you can do `map_items[item] = data;` or you can do `map_items.insert (item, data);` - which ever you like.

Comment: "I'm getting **double** type data"... "I realize that it **isn't double**"... Clarify your statements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are asking how to convert string to double (that is how I interpret the phrase "array[x] itself isn't a double but it represents a double").

You may use the `std::stod` function for that:

```
double stod (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0);
double stod (const wstring& str, size_t* idx = 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your definition of data (a double) is masking the previous definition for data (the array)

```
double data = data[x];
```

Did you mean to do:

```
double data = array[x];
```

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry for the mistake. Its changed. Thanks See edit.